# Cloudaccess.com , joomla 3, my template and custom.css issue

Tags: css, templates, joomla

Im designing a joomla website with my own template on cloudaccess.com
and im experiencing a strange issue.

My template is uploaded on my server and installed in joomla. 
It even loads nicely.
I created the file custom.css inside my templates css folder to customize it even further BUT when i reload the font-end page on cloudaccess.com, the custom.css never loads although it is present in the folder. For some reason joomla doesnt read it and i dont know why because locally on my computer with xampp it loads just fine!

Any idea why this bizzare problem appears?

[screenshot of the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/748zD.png)

Comment: It may be a matter of clearing the cache

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when the Custom CSS is not loaded to the template. Ensure that there is a link to the Custom CSS file. If one does not exist, add the following to your default.css file

```
<link href="{path}/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: you are absolutely right. I figured it out once i googled it more today.
I didnt declare my custom.css in my framework and upon compiling it didnt placed the jdoc code inside the index.php.